# How to access var by constructing name using variable and a string

Tags: c#, dynamic-variables

In PHP you can do the following to access a variable:

```
$foobar1 = 00.00;
$foobar2 = 11.11;
$foobar3 = 22.22;
$i = 2;

echo ${'foobar' . $i}; //Prints 11.11
```

I want to do the same in C# but I can't seem to get this to work:

```
double foobar1 = 00.00;
double foobar2 = 11.11;
double foobar3 = 22.22;
int i = 2;

Print("foobar" + i); //Should print 11.11
```

Any ideas? I have tried a few different searches but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Cheers!

Comment: Why you need that? If all variables have similar meaning you should put them in a `double[]` or  `List<double>`. If you really need a mapping from the name to the value you could use a `Dictionary<string, double>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to dynamically reference a *variable* by constructing its name. You can use reflection for properties, etc.

I would recommend using an array or list:

```
double[] foobar = { 00.00, 11.11, 22.22 };
int i = 2 - 1; // arrays are 0-based

Print(foobar[i]); //Does print 11.11
```